# Xamarin Forms Entry Focus When Containing ContentView is Shown

Tags: xamarin.forms, focus

I have a `MyView.xaml.cs` and `MyView.xaml` which is a `ContentView`.  It has an `Entry` field.

How do I focus on that Entry field each time MyView is shown on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Focus method on your PAGE when your View will be appearing like :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Entry entry = this.FindByName<Entry>("YourEntryName");
    entry.Focus();
}
```